# Save image to device with coredata

Tags: ios, core-data

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];


    NSManagedObject *image = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                              images.image = image;

                              [image setValue:tmpphoto forKey:@"img"];

                               CGSize size = tmpphoto.size;
                               CGFloat ratio = 0;
                               if (size.width > size.height) {
                                   ratio = 90.0 / size.width;
                               } else {
                                   ratio = 90.0 / size.height;
                               }
                               CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);

                               UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
                               [tmpphoto drawInRect:rect];

                               images.imaget = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                               UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

My entity name is "Image" with attributes img(transformable), imgcode(string)  im trying to save this image to my device with core data.But i have this error,what can be the problem?  Thank you in advance...

Error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't merge models with two different entities named 'Image''

Comment: I can't comment on the Core Data aspect of your question but two observations: 1. You can use [`UIImagePNGRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to retrieve image, rather than your graphics context methods; 2. Images (unless very small, less than 100kb) are not well suited for storing in CoreData.

Comment: and also when i comment these two lines
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

And instead of these line
  NSManagedObject *image = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; Im doing this my error is changing as  entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Image'???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    if (!currentPicture)
        self.currentPicture = (ImageList *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ImageList" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if (imageview.image)
    {
        float resize = 74.0;
        float actualWidth = imageview.image.size.width;
        float actualHeight = imageview.image.size.height;
        float divBy, newWidth, newHeight;
        if (actualWidth > actualHeight) {
            divBy = (actualWidth / resize);
            newWidth = resize;
            newHeight = (actualHeight / divBy);
        } else {
            divBy = (actualHeight / resize);
            newWidth = (actualWidth / divBy);
            newHeight = resize;
        }
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        [imageview.image drawInRect:rect];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSData *smallImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallImage, 1.0);
        [self.currentPicture setMyimage:smallImageData];
    }
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Failed to add new picture with error: %@", [error domain]);}
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *AlertCampo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"
" message:@"Your image successfully saved into your device"
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [AlertCampo show];
    }
```

With this i have solved my problem.Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Set type of you image property to `NSData` instead of transformable and when you want to get the image, get it using `PNG` representation.

[see this](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/188059_iphone-core-data-tutorial-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tmpphoto);
 NSManagedObject *image = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:context];
images.image  = image;

```
[image setValue:imageData forKey:@"img"];

CGSize size = tmpphoto.size;
CGFloat ratio = 0;
if (size.width > size.height) {
        ratio = 44.0 / size.width;
} else {
    ratio = 44.0 / size.height;
}
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[tmpphoto drawInRect:rect];
images.imaget = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I have changed like this and i have the same problem. And also in datamodel we dont have NSData option there.Binarydata and Tranformable option we have for the images